# .htaccess 503 redirect page & grant IP access issues

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ip

Firstly, When the 503 redirect lines are in place, I am able to redirect to the 503 page from my main page for example `www.myexample.com`, however if I then type some directories after that for example `www.myexample.com/about`, `www.myexample.com/contactme`, I am still able to access those sites, meaning I am only able to redirect none other than from my home page.

Secondly, the line that I have added specifically to only grant access to myself when the site is down does not seem to be working, I am still unable to access the site. What is wrong with that?
The following is my complete .htaccess file. I am guessing there are lines that counteract each other that may be causing my problem?

One last thing my .htaccess file is in the same folder as my public.html, not inside it. Not sure if that would cause any difference.

```
<FilesMatch "^\.htaccess"> 
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

php_flag display_startup_errors on
php_flag display_errors on
php_value upload_max_filesize 5M

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Remove .php
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

#404 error redirect
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

#503 temporary redirect #Problem here
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^xxx\.xxx\.x\.xx //my private IP address
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/503$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /503 [R,L]
```

Sorry for the unclear instruction earlier. 1: What I am trying to do is to make every directories beside my home page to redirect to my 503 page. 2: Another thing is to make my IP to be able to access the whole site while others can't when my 503 redirect is instructions activated.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions and solutions.

Ray

Comment: unclear what you asking. Can you add short and clear explanation what you want to get?

Comment: Sorry for the unclear instruction. 1: What I am trying to do is to make every directories beside my home page to redirect to my 503 page. 2: Another thing is to make my IP to be able to access the whole site while others can't when my 503 redirect is instructions activated.